# How to save option value from view to controller in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I want to save a select option value from view to controller.

Following is the Html code in view:-

```
<label for="delivery_option" class="prod-head size-head"><b>Select Delivery Option:</b></label>

                        <select id="payment_option" name="payment_option">
                            <option value="">Select</option>
                          <option value="A">Pick up product from pick up center</option>
                          <option value="B">Ship to my address</option>
                        </select>
```

Following is the jQuery code in view:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.payment').on('click',function(){
        var paymentName = $('#payment_option').find(":selected").val();
        if(paymentName==''){
            alert("Please select Payment Option");
        }else{
            var count = "{{ $error_count }}";
                if (count<1) {
                    $('#shopping_bag_form').submit();
                } else{
                    swal({
                      title: "Please remove unavailable product from the cart",
                      icon: "error",
                      dangerMode: true,
                      buttons: "Ok",
                    }).then((ok) => {
                        return false;
                    })
                }

        }

    });
</script>
```

I have used `$request->all();` option in controller to get the value, but it is showing only `_token` value. How can I send `payment_option` value to controller.

Answer (score 0):

As you already use jQuery, then use $[ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)-call.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'CONTROLLER_URL',
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (response) {
    }
        error: function (response) {
    }
});
```

In processData you can send any data you need. e.g. your #payment_option values